# How to capture Meta Data Info of Data sources used in DataStage

Tags: xml, metadata, workbench, datastage

The platform is IBM datastage 8.1. 
We don't have access to DataStage. We can only get .dsx/xml exported files.

Now we need to capture metadata information of which databases/tables(source) are transformed to another databases/tables(target).

Once we have that list of databases/tables used in DS jobs, we will put this information in Metadata workbench for Data Lineage purpose.

Is there another way i can get such information? Any thoughts or ideas will be a great help to me.

Thanks You in advance....

Answer (score 0):

you should request from your datastage team that they use the metadata database bundled with datastage, i.e. there is a script that should insert the data from the xml files into that database,
and to my knowledge you could use this same database with the metadate workbench as well.